# asp.net MVC2 Books

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know this has been asked many times but its been more for MVC1. I don't know if it matters all that much if its a MVC1 or a MVC2 book. But what I am looking for is a good book to get me started on asp.net MVC2 and a other book to read after for further reading. Now if these two books could be warped up into the that would be great.

I am aiming to learn enough so I can show some people in our team it. In the hope of it been a new way of working.

thanks
Antony

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any new ASP.NET MVC 2.0 resources or books that are recommended?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129469/are-there-any-new-asp-net-mvc-2-0-resources-or-books-that-are-recommended)

Comment: another dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701828

Comment: Both of these dupes show up in the Related Questions for your question title.

Comment: whats that saying again? oh yeah. Can't see for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steve Sanderson's Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 book is what you want http://blog.stevensanderson.com/category/pro-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: Agreed - I've read both versions and I view them as essential for anybody developing ASP.NET MVC applications professionally.

Answer (score 1):

Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework, Second Edition
http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430228865